# Unable to update a cache with persistent entity after saving the list of entities into table using JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa, concurrenthashmap

I have a scenario where I store the object into a cache bucket which is a ConcurrentHashMap for further processing that too before saving it into table.

`cacheObj.getMap().put(myObject, someLongID);`

After that I add the entity into a List and save the list of entities into table.

`listBatch.add(myObject);`

`myRepo.saveAll(listBatch);`

Now my question is how can I update the cache with persistent entity so that I can make changes to it as well if needed and update table. I can't move the cache data population after save.

I have another cache bucket where key is the ID and object is in value, just opposite of above bucket because of requirement where I want to do same scenario as above.

`cache.anotherBucket = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, MyClass>();`

Comment: It is a bad idea to cache entities yourself without understanding in-depth what your provider does and how it manages entities and changes. You will get into all sorts of concurrency, stale data, dirty reads and other issues if you just take objects and hold them for the life of the app without mechanisms to copy/clone, invalidate, refresh and purge from the cache - all things your JPA provider already has, and most can already support a second level cache/global cache. What happens to your cache data if the transaction fails?

Comment: Its not actually a cache like redis or memcache, Its named as cache as it stores the entities required for processing for different classes for certain period which gets cleared later point of time. Its basically a class having several Map buckets.

Comment: Which is a cache, is it not? What is the point of a map holding incomplete transactional data? It is invalid as soon as the transaction commits, or any other transaction touching those same data points commits - or worse, gets overwritten with concurrent uncommitted data. But your question - you have a way to set the data in, so you must have a way to update/correct the data once the transaction commits. Update the object in the buckets directly, or replace it with a new instance.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your issue: If the issue is you've cached using (myObject, someLongID) as well as (id ,object), then you'll have to make two lookups when doing object replacements in these buckets, first on the ID to get the object, then use the object in the other bucket. Caching using the data (myObjdct) as the key might not be the best choice though.